# Can't Control Brightness on HP Envy All-in-One 24-n014

Tags: multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, brightness, hp

I haven't been able to control the bightness on my computer.  It is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and dual boots with Windows 10.  My processor is an Intel Core i5-6400T and my graphics card is an Intel HD Graphics 530 (Skylake GT2), if that helps.  From what research I've done, the Skylake architecture is not very well supported on Ubuntu, at the moment.  When on my Windows partition, I can control the screen fine, *and* my speakers which I have asked another question on.  If there is anything I might be able to do, I will gladly try it. Thanks for any replies.

Edit1:  I also use an HDMI to VGA adapter for a second monitor if that helps.  Also my main monitor is an integrated computer (All-in-One).

Have a good one.

Answer (score 0):

In linux you can control screen brightness by writing to `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`. Execute this command and enter password when asked:

`echo 50|sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`

The brightness should become low. 50 here is the level of backlight you want. It's interpreted relative to a maximum value. You can see this fixed maximum value by executing `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness`.You can make a set of programs to modify brightness and assign keys to them using xbindkeys(this is what I've done). Ask if you need details.

Note: The path of the file can be a bit different based on your hardware. It will be somewhere in the `/sys/class/backlight` directory.

Comment: Should my max brightness be 937?  `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness` returned `cat /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/max_brightness 
937`

Comment: It could be anything depending on the hardware. Funny enough it can change with time as well. A few months ago it was 225 on my lappy, today I found it to be 234.  `/sys`  is a virtual file system which provides an interface to the kernel internals.

Comment: BTW 937 is the output, not the return value of command. See bash manual for difference.